# PHP - exec function not working when XAMPP when running as Service

Tags: php, module, xampp

I have very strange behavior on XAMPP app.

I developed a website which runs a bat files (for internal use), when user click on a button bat file run on the server.

the problem is when I configure the Apache & MySQL as service (see the below screen) the exec function is not running the bat file.

[image]

but when I disable the service for both of the modules (Apache & MySQL) the exec is works.

Has someone faced this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Are you sure that the user who launches the process has enough permissions?

Comment: No error on the apache log.
The user who launches the process have permission. (The user can run the process when the service disable).